# Profiling the MongoDB database to see the executed queries

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way to see the executed queries on MongoDB? I enabled profiling through the mongo.exe on windows with the following command:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2);
```

This enables profiling and I can query the profile data with the following command for example:

```
db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()
```

However, this doesn't get me the executed queries. I know that I can also use the `IMongoQuery.ToJson()` method to see the query but I am using Linq queries with MongoDB C# Driver (BTW, I really wonder why they called this C# driver instead of .NET driver).

Here is the sample:

```
var people = db.GetCollection<Person>("People")
    .AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Sessions.Any(y => y.SessionDate != null));

var peeps = people.Select(x => 
    x.Sessions.Where(y => y.SessionDate != null)).ToList();
```

However, that would be really cool to be able to do the following:

```
var people = db.GetCollection<Person>("People")
    .AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Sessions.Any(y => y.SessionDate != null))
    .Expression.ToJson();
```

But this is not supported I guess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to do it without getting the `IMongoQuery`. The good news is that you can cast `people` to a `MongoQueryable<Person>` and get the `IMongoQuery` from there:

```
var people = db.GetCollection<Person>("People")
    .AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Sessions.Any(y => y.SessionDate != null));

var mqPeople = (MongoQueryable<Person>)people;
var query = mqPeople.GetMongoQuery().ToJson();
```

**Edit:**

It looks like this will only work for the `Where` clause though.

Comment: This looks quite right. Thanks for bringing this up. I'll give it a try but I am assuming that any supported Linq method which returns IQueryable should be seen as `MongoQueryable<T>`.

Comment: For the most part that is a valid assumption (for the `Where` clause). If it isn't a `MongoQueryable<T>` then it is likely that portion of the Linq statement will be run on the client and not the server, which may hint at more ways you can optimize.