# How can I retrieve the MongoDB query from IMongoQueryable in the 2.5 .NET Core driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to get the MongoDB query from an *IMongoQueryable* expression with the latest C# Driver 2.5 in .NET Core 2.0.

Most of the examples of older versions say I should do something like this:

```
((MongoQueryable<TModel>)_collection.AsQueryable()).GetMongoQuery();
```

(from [Profiling the MongoDB database to see the executed queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901822/profiling-the-mongodb-database-to-see-the-executed-queries) in 2012)

So in my code, I try to get the MongoDB query like this:

```
// Create the filter query.
IQueryable<TModel> modelQuery = _collection.AsQueryable()
    .Where(t => t.TeamId == teamId && t.CompanyId == companyId);

// Get the query as it will be executed in MongoDB.
var mquery = (MongoQueryable<TModel>)modelQuery; // This line shows the error below.
var query = mquery.GetMongoQuery().ToJson();

// Get the results.
var models = modelQuery.ToList();
```

However, I get the error:

> The non-generic type 'MongoQueryable' cannot be used with type
>   arguments

The *MongoQueryable* referenced in my code is a static extension methods class. The *MongoQueryable* referenced by the other examples seems to be located in the *MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll*, so I assume it is not ported to .NET Core? I also cannot find this *.dll* in the NuGet package for .NET Core.

Is there any other way to achieve getting the actual MongoDB query from the *IMongoQueryable* expression?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do with it? Can yo share some code?

Comment: @jpgrassi I added the code snipped. I am trying to see the query as the MongoDB driver will execute it on the MongoDB. The examples I have seen are quite old and I can't get those to work with the .NET Core version of the driver.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/ec74978f7e827515f29cc96fba0c727828e8df7c/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/MongoQueryableIntComparedToNullableIntTests.cs#L49

Comment: And also this.. which outputs the same results: http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Linq_IMongoQueryable_GetExecutionModel.htm

Comment: Wow, that easy? I'm impressed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jpgrassi, I managed with the following code:

```
// Create the filter query.
IQueryable<TModel> modelQuery = _collection.AsQueryable()
    .Where(t => t.TeamId == teamId && t.CompanyId == companyId);

// Get the query as it will be executed in MongoDB.
var mquery = (MongoQueryable<TModel>)modelQuery; // This line shows the error below.
var query = mquery.GetMongoQuery().ToJson();

// Get the results.
var models = modelQuery.ToList();

// Get the executed query string.
var executionModel = ((IMongoQueryable<TModel>)modelQuery).GetExecutionModel();
var queryString = executionModel.ToString();
```

In my case, this outputs an aggregate query like this:

```
aggregate([{ "$match" : { "TeamId" : ...
```

This query I can now easily paste into my query editor and play around with it. Awesome!